# jQuery show/hide div on hover (multipule instances)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 6 thumbnails with 6 hidden captions in a separate div. I'd like to display the respective caption on hover and hide it again on rollout.

At the moment I've managed to get it working using the `.hide();` and `.show();` methods but if the user has rolled over any of the thumbnails before the page has fully loaded the captions stack on top of each other and don't seem to toggle visibility properly.

EDIT - Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vd0zd3z6/) I put together which shows it in action however I can't seem to replicate the problem seen here http://2xdare.co/projects/
(Try refreshing whilst hovering over thumbnails)

I assume this is something to do with how I'm calling the script in relation to the DOM - but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (my knowledge of jQuery & Javascript is very limited)

Thumbnail:

```
<a class="imagelink post1" href=""><div class="thumb"></div></a>
```

Caption:

```
<div class="caption-container">
    <div class="projectcaptions hide-mobile">
      <div class="surgedesc">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p class="fields">Field captions</p>
        <p class="captions">Captions</p>
      </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


//  Mobile Nav
jQuery(function($){
         $( '#nav-toggle' ).click(function(){
             $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
             $('.main-header').toggleClass('blackout')
         })
    });
//  Coverfade element
$(window).scroll(function(i){
    var scrollVar = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.coverelement, #arrow').css({
        'opacity':( 300-$(window).scrollTop() )/300
    });
});

//  CAPTION ROLLOVER
$(window).load(function(){
    var cancel = false;
    $("div.surgedesc").hide();
    $(".post1").hover(function(){
        cancel = (cancel)?false: true;    
        if(!cancel){
        $("div.surgedesc").hide();
        }
        else if(cancel){
        $("div.surgedesc").show();
        }    
    });
    var cancel = false;
    $("div.linierdesc").hide();
    $(".post2").hover(function(){
        cancel = (cancel)?false: true;    
        if(!cancel){
        $("div.linierdesc").hide();
        }
        else if(cancel){
        $("div.linierdesc").show();
        }    
    });
    var cancel = false;
    $("div.we-are-foreverdesc").hide();
    $(".post3").hover(function(){
        cancel = (cancel)?false: true;    
        if(!cancel){
        $("div.we-are-foreverdesc").hide();
        }
        else if(cancel){
        $("div.we-are-foreverdesc").show();
        }    
    });
    var cancel = false;
    $("div.worth-popupdesc").hide();
    $(".post4").hover(function(){
        cancel = (cancel)?false: true;    
        if(!cancel){
        $("div.worth-popupdesc").hide();
        }
        else if(cancel){
        $("div.worth-popupdesc").show();
        }    
    });
    var cancel = false;
    $("div.walk-the-linedesc").hide();
    $(".post5").hover(function(){
        cancel = (cancel)?false: true;    
        if(!cancel){
        $("div.walk-the-linedesc").hide();
        }
        else if(cancel){
        $("div.walk-the-linedesc").show();
        }    
    });
    var cancel = false;
    $("div.the-looking-glassdesc").hide();
    $(".post6").hover(function(){
        cancel = (cancel)?false: true;    
        if(!cancel){
        $("div.the-looking-glassdesc").hide();
        }
        else if(cancel){
        $("div.the-looking-glassdesc").show();
        }    
    });


}); 
});
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Could you work this up into a Fiddle/JS Bin that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @MattD I'll put together a Fiddle now! In the mean time you can see the problem here: http://2xdare.co/projects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your cancel variables is a problem and not useful and the right structure in jquery to use hover effect

```
$("selector").hover(function(){
//do something when it is hover
},function(){
//do something when you lose hover
});
```

and this a example for you first post

`$(".post1").hover(function() {
    $("div.surgedesc").show();
  }, function() {
     $("div.surgedesc").hide();
  });`

you can read more about this here https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Solves the problem! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your `cancel` variables are not unique to each hover event as it appears is the intention. Rather, it is a single variable shared with all 6 sections.

Do you have access to the DOM markup? I find it more maintainable to define a custom attribute in the HTML itself and have JS use that value when needed:

```
<div class="caption-container">
    <div class="projectcaptions hide-mobile">
      <div data-showonhover=".post1">...</div>
      <div data-showonhover=".post2">...</div>
      <div data-showonhover=".post3">...</div>
      <div data-showonhover=".post4">...</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Then you can find any element using this custom attribute and `toggle()` the target on hover:

```
$("[data-showonhover]").hover(function(){
    $($(this).data("showonhover")).toggle();
});
```

Comment: I do have access to the DOM markup. I did think it bad practice having to repeat that code, this makes a lot more sense. How would I go about implementing this in my code? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vd0zd3z6/)